# Dealing with race conditions in ruby scripts run concurrently

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, deadlock, race-condition

I have a rake tasks which planned to be run in **multiple copies at the same time.** It'll process data from a DB:

```
data_to_process = MyModel.
   where.not(status: :being_processed).
   limit(333)

for item in data_to_process do
  item.status = :being_processed

  # send API request
  res = send_api_request(item.data1)
  # it may take 30...60 seconds

  item.data2 = res["data2"]
end
```

How will I avoid race conditions here?

Namely, I run a 1st copy, it begings to process, let's say, `1...333`th records, processes 10 of them, and then a 2nd gets launched. And then, after a little while,  a 3rd, 4th... copies get launched. So any subsequent copy would grad a subset of the **unprocessed records** of the previous one.

How to deal with it? Given that an API request will take relatively long time. And which means that all those requests, `333` in this case, perhaps may not be wrapped into a **single** DB transaction or some lock.

Or how would make a new copy of the script **allocate** a list of records for itself right aways by updating `status = being_proccessed` **atomically and exclusively**? So that it'll then be processing the records by itself with no race condition issue.

Would `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` help here?

The possibility of a deadlock must be kept in mind.

Comment: @spickermann I already know about that. I'm asking how to apply anything that may work in my case

Comment: @spickermann I've also addresses the point about pessimistic locking as well: each copy of the script will take around 1 or a few hours to process its records. Do you suggest to open a db trransaction or lock per script for this long ?

Comment: You can not hold hundreds of heavy external api requests in active record transaction or locking mechanism. It is not efficient. I suggest you should use an active job framework. Sidekiq is a good solution. You can easily create hundreds of multi threads working concurrently. And deal with failed, retried, dead jobs with the help of Redis.

Comment: @titan2gman I suggest to avoid giving suggestions without knowing one's situation

Comment: Which dbms are you using?